# Get files from s3 bucket after some number of files using list_objects_v2?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using python Boto3 library:

```
def get_all_s3_objects(s3, **base_kwargs):
    continuation_token = None
    while True:
        list_kwargs = dict(MaxKeys=1000, **base_kwargs)
        if continuation_token:
            list_kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = continuation_token
        response = s3.list_objects_v2(**list_kwargs)
        yield response.get('Contents', [])
        if not response.get('IsTruncated'):  # At the end of the list?
            break
        continuation_token = response.get('NextContinuationToken')

Allobjects = get_all_s3_objects(client, 
                        Bucket = s3Bucket,
                        Prefix = targetFolder+'/'
                        # StartAfter = 'jupiter-ai/78410/7bd7a4a2adb32ad5723ae06c9a644b87/17.jpg'
                    )
```

StartAfter requires a key if you want to get data after this key, but in my case, I want to get data after some number of files. like  `StartAfter = 5000`, this means after 5000 files I want data as list_objects_v2 traverse files alphabetically.
But I cannot find anything in the docs.
How can I achieve this without traversing the whole set of data in s3?

Comment: You can't. You need to retrieve the list based on the keys and simply discard the first 5000 matches.

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to skip the first 5000 objects?